# how to restore .bkp file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have a `.bkp` file, how can I restore it to SQL Server?

I have SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012.

Any idea?

Comment: [RESTORE DATABASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx)

Comment: let's google up this type doubts!!!

Comment: Usually SQL Server backup files are `.bak`. Is the file actually a SQL Server backup, or is it from another source?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a SQL Server backup file from a version earlier than 2008 or 2012 (or the same version, you can not restore a Sql Server 2012 backup file to a Sql Server 2008 instance) you can restore it to a new database by using the following command:

`RESTORE DATABASE NewDBName 
   FROM DISK = N'PathToBackupFile'
   WITH MOVE 'LogicalDataFileName' TO 'PathTo.mdf',
        MOVE 'LogicalLogFileName' TO 'PathTo.log',
        STATS=10`

This will create a new database from the backup.  If you want to restore to an existing database you would modify the restore command above to restore to the target database instead of a new database.  You also may need to add REPLACE as well if you are restoring to an existing database.

[Restore Database Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To use SQL Server Management Studio options:

1. Right click **Databases** in **Object Explorer**
2. Select **Restore Database**

[image]

3.Select **Device** and click **...**

4.In the **Select backup devices** dialog, click **Add**

[image]

5.Make sure **All files** option is selected. By default, only bak and trn files are shown

[image]

6.Click **OK** and that's it

[image]

Note that you can restore a backup only if it has been created on the same SQl Server version, or earlier (but not SQL Server 2000 on 2012)

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation on how to restore a database backup at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx

If you run into a problem, please edit your question adding the specifics of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can only restore backups in its own format (mostly named .bak). bkp files could be from oracle or progress - you know best which product. You have to import the data manually into sql server after restoring it in the original program.