# What does sp_restore_filelistonly do?

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2017

In SQL Server 2017, after applying Cumulative Update 7, there's a new system stored procedure in master called sp_restore_filelistonly. What's it for?

Answer (score 3):

sp_restore_filelistonly is a (currently) undocumented stored procedure with two parameters:

- @device_type NVARCHAR(10) - like 'DISK'
- @backup_path NVARCHAR(360) - which needs to point to the exact backup file you want to example, not just the folder path where it lives

When you point it at a backup file, like this:

```
EXEC sp_restore_filelistonly
    @device_type = 'DISK',
    @backup_path = 'E:\MSSQL2017\Backup\StackOverflow2010.bak';
```

It functions like RESTORE FILELISTONLY:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'E:\MSSQL2017\Backup\StackOverflow2010.bak' WITH FILE = 1;
```

You get an output set with the files included in the backup:

[image]

- LogicalName
- PhysicalName
- Type (D for full, L for log, etc)
- FileGroupName
- Size (in bytes)
- MaxSize
- FileId
- CreateLSN
- DropLSN
- UniqueID
- ReadOnlyLSN
- ReadWriteLSN
- BackupSizeInBytes - note that this is the uncompressed size, so if your backup used compression, you won't see the real file size here
- SourceBlockSize
- FileGroupId
- LogGroupGUID
- DifferentialBaseLSN
- DifferentialBaseGUID
- IsReadOnly
- IsPresent
- TDEThumbprint
- SnapshotUrl

Why would Microsoft build it? Well, if they want to let someone get a file list without running a RESTORE command. Could be a separation-of-duties thing, or could be making the automation plumbing easier for Azure Managed Instances.

Comment: `EXEC sp_helptext 'sys.sp_restore_filelistonly'` shows it's just a wrapper that executes `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` with either the `URL` or `DISK` keyword depending on the specified @device_type`.

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to balance the sp_attach_db, as a wrapper for CREATE DATABASE --- FOR ATTACH. I.e., have use use the sp, then remove it at some later point so we need to re-write our scripts - job security for the DBAs.